# Sync file's cache to the disk or clear the file's cache in the memory

Tags: c#, windows, command-line, filesystems, synchronization

In windows, have any command line or API can do the below questions (for internal hard disk)?

1. Force sync the file's cache in the memory to disk.
2. Clear the file's cache in the memory and reload files from the disk.
3. Force sync the disk's file-cache in the memory to disk.
4. Clear the disk's file-cache in the memory and reload files from the disk.

Does anyone have similar experiences?

Comment: What's the idea behind 2 and 4? Windows absolutely assumes that the in-cache representation is leading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/259577/How-to-flush-a-storage-volumes-the-file-cache-lock

The link fix the question 2 and 4. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364439(v=vs.85).aspx

But the API is for a file, not for a disk.

Can I flush all file's buffers in the target disk?

Comment: "To flush all open files on a volume, call `FlushFileBuffers` with a handle to the volume. The caller must have administrative privileges." A physical disk may hold multiple volumes so you should enumerate those, assuming that you really meant a physical disk.

Comment: MSalters, thanks for your help!  It is success!!
My question have only 2 and 4.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: My idea is simply: don't do 2 and 4. There are rare cases where the idea makes sense theoretically, but in those cases you'd be talking about a file system driver which is located _below_ the caching layer, not above (where C# and the command line are).